# Service fabric reverse proxy with certificates on endpoint

Tags: azure, reverse-proxy, azure-service-fabric

In Service Fabric, is it possible to require certificates for users/clients accessing the http endpoints when using the reverse proxy?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it is possible -

> SSL termination happens at the reverse proxy and all the client
>   certificate data is lost. For the services to perform client
>   certificate authentication, set the **ForwardClientCertificate** setting
>   in the parameters section of ApplicationGateway/Http element.
>
> When **ForwardClientCertificate** is set to **true**, reverse proxy requests
>   for the client's certificate during its SSL handshake with the client.
>   It will then forward the client certificate data in a custom HTTP
>   header named **X-Client-Certificate**.

Check out [Setting up client certificate authentication through the reverse proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy-configure-secure-communication#setting-up-client-certificate-authentication-through-the-reverse-proxy).

Comment: Does that mean when I set the ForwardClientCertificate to true, I would need to do anything to my services? Or would they automatically check the header with a client certificate that's installed on the cluster?

Comment: @DaveN It depends...what's the need of certificates at the first place? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just want to be able to use the reverse proxy and also have certificate based security on all users/clients that access service endpoints. I was hoping there would be a setting on the fabric cluster as opposed to having to write any code or do any configuring on the service level.

Comment: @DaveN As far as I know, there is no such a thing. Take a look at what the official documentation says - "Reverse proxy is a mere forwarder. It will not perform any validation of the client's certificate.", meaning you are the one who is responsible for implementing the certificates validation in the service.

Comment: Ok, and if we weren't using the reverse proxy, is there a way to secure the endpoints by certificates out of the box?

Comment: @DaveN If you're asking for SF built-in feature to have your service authenticating clients via certificates just with a push of a button, then my answer is no. But it should not be that hard to implement, there is a plenty of good examples around, especially if you're dealing with asp.net core service.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. We have services on core and .net framework. Do you know of an easy alternative to add a something in front of our cluster to do authorization/authentication security prior to the cluster being accessed? API Gateway standard looks pretty expensive and I didn't want to yet incorporate code to do the authentication/authorization on all of our services. We only have one system that needs to access the cluster endpoints.

Comment: @DaveN If your concern is implementing the same authentication logic in multiple services, I'd advise the approach of having a dedicated service that LB will redirect all the requests at. That very service would authenticate the incoming request, and then redirect it through SF ReverseProxy toward a target service. That's kind of approach I've implemented for the multi-tenant app on the project of mine.

Answer (score 0):

For service fabric azure, you can put Azure Application Gateway in front of service fabric and its reverse proxy and do SSL off loading so HTTPS come to Application Gateway get validated and convert to HTTP before before reaching the service.

It give benefit of less maintenance effort, if you have a request which then trigger 5 services to call each other in a chain using reverse proxy with Forward Certificate option on then each services will have to be config to deal with https. If there is a change to certificate ie expire then you have to update all services configuration With application gateway you only do at one place.

It is also better for resilient because if you prefix a particular reverse proxy in a node then if that node is down you lost connection. Having Application Gateway will allow you to remove that node and use reverse proxy on other node

For on premise solution you can do the same depend on your own load balancer